# switch tab by using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a user of my webpage presses the tab 2 if he press next I want show him next tab. i.e. tab 3. I don't know how to relate both values to each other.

If we are able to store the tab value somewhere and the buttons can access that value, after these we can change the tab by increment or decrement.

I want to relate tabs with buttons. When the user clicks tab 3 it will open tab 3 and hide other tabs. When the user clicks on the "next" button tab 4 should be shown.

Comment: Have you considered using any frameworks? Bootstrap has a full solution for tabs.

Comment: here what i want, change the tab by buttons.

Comment: This question has been answered many times. Please review this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171504/change-active-tab-on-button-click

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indicate how many tabs you have. Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic implementation using data attributes on HTML.

Idea is upon button click to retrieve the data attribute value (id of the corresponding HTML tab content) and to make it active while hiding all others.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-container > button");
const content = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content-container > *");

buttons.forEach(button=>{
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
      const id = this.dataset.target;
      const target = document.querySelector(id);
      content.forEach(ele=>{
        if(ele === target) ele.classList.add("active");
        else ele.classList.remove("active");
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.tab-content-container {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tab-content-container > .active {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content-container">
  <div id="content-1">
    Content 1
  </div>

  <div id="content-2">
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-container">
  <button data-target="#content-1">Tab 1</button>
  <button data-target="#content-2">Tab 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small vanillaJS codepen for you. It is not totally optimized (redundency in code) but it works fine :)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMqgNp

```
document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a").forEach(function(e) {
  e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Removing all active
    document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a.active, .tabs > .tab.active").forEach(function(b) {
      b.classList.remove("active");
    });

    // Activating tab
    e.classList.add("active");
    var tabid = e.getAttribute("data-tab");
    document.querySelector(".tab[data-tab='"+ tabid +"']").classList.add("active");
  });
})

// Next button
document.querySelector("#next").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var tabid = parseInt(document.querySelector(".tabs > .tab.active").getAttribute("data-tab"))+1;
  if(tabid > document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a").length) tabid = 1;
  document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a.active, .tabs > .tab.active").forEach(function(b) {
      b.classList.remove("active");
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a[data-tab='"+tabid+"'], .tabs > .tab[data-tab='"+tabid+"']").forEach(function(b) {
      b.classList.add("active");
    });
});

// Prev button
document.querySelector("#back").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var tabid = parseInt(document.querySelector(".tabs > .tab.active").getAttribute("data-tab"))-1;
  if(tabid < 1) tabid = document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a").length;
  document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a.active, .tabs > .tab.active").forEach(function(b) {
      b.classList.remove("active");
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(".tabscontroller a[data-tab='"+tabid+"'], .tabs > .tab[data-tab='"+tabid+"']").forEach(function(b) {
      b.classList.add("active");
    });
});
```

Edit: Added Prev button Back

Comment: perfect. can we make for previous button also. as i newbie in javascript. not good in query selector so please

Comment: I added the back button to the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMqgNp
I also added the explaination to the response.